# For a given fixed perimeter p, what will be the width of a Norman window in order to maximize its area?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, area, maxima-minima

A Norman window is a rectangle with a semicircle on top. For a given fixed perimeter p, what will be the width of the window in order to maximize its area?

Comment: MSE isn't a question answering service. You need to tell us something about your work on the problem.

Comment: I'm not just looking for an answer, I'm trying to understand how to approach a problem like this. When numbers are involved I know how to do most of my calc assignments, but what I'm lacking right now is a deeper understanding of what the results mean, and how to get there. That's why I come to MSE, because you guys DO understand and can help me out. :)

Comment: Start by finding a formula for the perimeter and the area of the window.

Comment: OK, so phrase your question to reflect what you've written in your comment, maybe you could say that you know how to calculate the area given the perimeter and the width but you don't know how to find the width that maximises the area. That shows us that you've worked on the problem and gives us an idea about how to help. (You now have an answer with some great hints from Henry.)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Suppose width of the window is $w$

- What is the radius of the semicircle?
- What is the length of the curved part the semicircle?
- What is the height of the rectangle in terms of $p$ and $w$?
- What is the area of the window (the rectangle plus the semicircle) in terms of $p$ and $w$?
- For given $p$, which $w$ maximises the area of the window?